# Is it good practice to save the Images/Files in the current working directory in c# project

Tags: c#, wpf, image, file, desktop-application

Is it good practice to save the Images/Files in the current working directory in c# project. Or it is better to save them as other project files and folders independent of the program execution.

Answer (score 2):

Better to use a safer place instead execution location. Take a place where the user has file write access like Documents, AppData etc. Because the application might be run in the different place where in some places possible user has no file write access, then you won't be able to save any images/files  there.

Comment: Current working directory is not program location...

Comment: but I guess OP ask about the current program execution directory

Answer (score 0):

This is an opinion based question. But still I will share my opinion.
You can keep all the images within a specific folder within your project. Such as an **Image** folder or whatever name you would like to give it.

While adding the item to your project, you can click on properties of the image and specify the Build Action to `Resource` in the properties window.

[image: Refer this image]

Specify the UriSource property as :

UriSource="/images/abcd.png"

That URI is effectively a Resource File Pack URI,and the prefix would be automatically added, so you need not worry about copying the image file to output directory.